# Local PHP Proxy

Tags: php, javascript, xml, proxy, local

I'm developing a Javascript application that fetches and manipulates a large quantity of XML documents. This script is meant to be run locally, from the user's computer.

Enter Same-Origin Policy.

I'v looked at quite a few options to get around this barrier, but none of them seem practical in this situation. I originality dismissed a PHP proxy, since the JS is local. But now I'm wondering if it's possible to run the requests through a PHP proxy on the user's computer, thus bypassing cross-domain restrictions.

Is there any way to do this or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a javascript file using the file protocol (file:///), some browsers will allow cross-domain requests.

This is because browsers assume things originating from a local computer will be 100% completely trusted.

You can run a php proxy but that requires an application server, and php interpreter to be installed.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this: Internet Explorer WILL run the script, but crashes about 1/40 of the way in. (Google Chrome can run it without crashing, if you use the `--disable-web-security` flag.) Do you know what browsers will run cross-domain requests from a local file?

Comment: Chrome is the only one I know for sure, there is probably some kind of workaround for other browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "crossdomain ajax". For example, first results for me: http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide and http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html